# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, cors, laravel-5.4

I have a problem with CORS using javascript.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

To fix this issue I install [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package

But it didn't help at all. Can some one advice me how to fix this problem? How can I debug it to see where is the problem and why this package not working?

This is my code.

In `\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
```

In `\config\app.php`

```
'providers' => [
       Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
 ],
```

In `\config\cors.php`

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

End my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    fx.base = "EUR";
    fx.settings = {
        from : "EUR"
    };

    var amount = 9.99; //in SolidShops, you could use: {{ product.price }}
    // Load exchange rates data via the cross-domain/AJAX proxy:

    $.getJSON(
        'http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json',
        function(data) {
            // Check money.js has finished loading:
            if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
                fx.rates = data.rates;
                fx.base = data.base;
            } else {
                // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                var fxSetup = {
                    rates : data.rates,
                    base : data.base
                }
            }

            // now that we have exchange rates, add a few to our page
            var USD = fx.convert(amount, {to: "USD"}); //13.22784197768393
            var GBP = fx.convert(amount, {to: "GBP"}); //8.567532636985659
            var JPY = fx.convert(amount, {to: "JPY"}); //1028.1670562349989

            // we can now use the accounting.js library to format the numbers properly
            USD = accounting.formatMoney(USD, "$ ", 2, ",", ".");
            GBP = accounting.formatMoney(GBP, "£ ", 2, ",", ".");
            JPY = accounting.formatMoney(JPY, "¥ ", 2, ",", ".");

            $("ul.currencies").append("<li>USD estimate: " + USD + "</li>");
            $("ul.currencies").append("<li>GBP estimate: " + GBP + "</li>");
            $("ul.currencies").append("<li>JPY estimate: " + JPY + "</li>");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Its been a while since I worked on Laravel but you could reference packages like these https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-api-boilerplate-jwt to understand what your doing wrong

Comment: @JackSlayer94 This is a brand new project how I understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instead use the URL https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json

---

The error message cited in the question indicates that the `openexchangerates.org` server isn’t sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header back to your code when your code makes a request to the URL `http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json`.

So it doesn’t matter what CORS config you do on your own server backend where your own code is being served from. The problem you ran into was only because of the `openexchangerates.org` not sending back that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

But if you instead use the right URL—https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json—then that server will send back the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its response, and you won’t get that *“CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing”* error message any longer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a newbie. I get this code in a tutorial that was out of date.